# cowbuilder --update W: --override-config is not set; not updating apt.conf Read the manpage for details

Tags: apt, cowbuilder

The following is my `~/.pbuilderrc`

```
$ cat .pbuilderrc 
BASEPATH="/var/cache/pbuilder/sid-amd64/base.cow"
DISTRIBUTION="sid"
MIRRORSITE="http://deb.debian.org/debian/"
# Enable build log
 PKGNAME_LOGFILE="yes"
```

whenever I run `sudo cowbuilder --update` I get the following warning -

```
$ sudo cowbuilder --update
I: Copying COW directory
I: forking: rm -rf /var/cache/pbuilder/build/cow.8567
I: forking: cp -al /var/cache/pbuilder/sid-amd64/base.cow /var/cache/pbuilder/build/cow.8567
I: unlink for ilistfile /var/cache/pbuilder/build/cow.8567/.ilist failed, it didn't exist?
I: Invoking pbuilder
I: forking: pbuilder update --buildplace /var/cache/pbuilder/build/cow.8567 --mirror http://deb.debian.org/debian/ --distribution sid --no-targz --internal-chrootexec 'chroot /var/cache/pbuilder/build/cow.8567 cow-shell'
I: Running in no-targz mode
I: Current time: Fri Aug 31 23:18:47 IST 2018
I: pbuilder-time-stamp: 1535737727
I: copying local configuration
W: --override-config is not set; not updating apt.conf Read the manpage for details.
```

Can somebody tell me what --override-config is all about and where it needs to be set and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--override-config` is a [`pbuilder` option](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/pbuilder/pbuilder.8.en.html), not a `cowbuilder` option. It instructs `pbuilder` to update the `apt` configuration in the base image.

`cowbuilder` runs `pbuilder update` with options which instruct it to use a different mirror and distribution. `pbuilder` warns about this when run without `--override-config` because end-users running it manually with those options might expect the changes to be persistent (since `update` is all about updating the base tarball). There’s nothing for you to do, apart from ignoring the warning.

Comment: Is there a way to run a "cowbuilder update" command to update the COW directory so that it thinks the new apt configuration is the original configuration so it stops outputting that error every time, even if --override-config is not used?